# What is the default sorting order for gamecenter leaderboard.

Tags: iphone, leaderboard

I am creating a leader board for my ios game. In itunesconnect, I can see two options

`Sort Order:    1.Low to High  2.High to Low`.

Its confusing. I want a normal leader-board with hiscore on the top. Right now I selected Low to High, to my horror sandbox returningonly lower scores.

Answer (score 4):

I know, this makes me look like a dumb-ass.

Apple clearly states that. By choosing `(?)`

```
Choose "High to Low" if you want highest scores displayed first.
Choose "Low to High" if you want lowest scores displayed first.
```

I was fooled cause itunesconnect display the option "Low to High"  first. I was thinking that, there is some problem with the sandbox account which doesn't update the score. In fact, it was always returning the lowest score. I always submitted the high score wondering ,why it is not updating. (So many people suggested that gc doesn't work properly on a sand box account and I believed)

So select `High to Low` (although its second option) for a normal option to see a leader-board like this.

```
Hi score
========
20000 (Top score)
10000
1000
1000
```

select `Low to high` a reverse list.

```
Failed attempts
===============
2 (Top score)
13
40
100
```

Careful, since you cant change this once your app gone live.(I realized my mistake  right now  - 5 days after the submission of my app -OMG, I submitted the app blaming sandbox account)

Comment: The reason you can't change it is because Apple uses this ordering to know whether a new score should replace a previous one. Low to High is good for racing times and that kind of thing whereby the faster (less time) is 'better'.

Comment: Good point. Once app got released, Does apple allows to submit the new update with deleting old leaderboard?